# How to import Postgres tables(Geometry format) into Hive using Sqoop?

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, sqoop

I have Postgres tables with Geometry type data.Now I am trying to import Postgres tables into Hive using Sqoop.Then its giving this errors,

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.130:5432/Analyst_Bangalore --username postgres --password track@123 --table state -m 1 --warehouse-dir /user/hive/warehouse/analytics.db

 ERROR orm.ClassWriter (ClassWriter.java:generateFields(560)) - Cannot resolve SQL type 1111
2016-10-20 15:52:30,115 ERROR orm.ClassWriter (ClassWriter.java:myGenerateEquals(645)) - Cannot resolve SQL type 1111
2016-10-20 15:52:30,115 ERROR orm.ClassWriter (ClassWriter.java:myGenerateEquals(645)) - Cannot resolve SQL type 1111
2016-10-20 15:52:30,115 ERROR orm.ClassWriter (ClassWriter.java:myGenerateDbRead(718)) - No Java type for SQL type 1111 for column the_geom
2016-10-20 15:52:30,115 ERROR orm.ClassWriter (ClassWriter.java:myGenerateDbRead(718)) - No Java type for SQL type 1111 for column the_geom
2016-10-20 15:52:30,115 ERROR orm.ClassWriter (ClassWriter.java:myGenerateLoadLargeObjects(798)) - No Java type for SQL type 1111 for column the_geom
2016-10-20 15:52:30,115 ERROR orm.ClassWriter (ClassWriter.java:myGenerateLoadLargeObjects(798)) - No Java type for SQL type 1111 for column the_geom
2016-10-20 15:52:30,115 ERROR orm.ClassWriter (ClassWriter.java:myGenerateDbWrite(884)) - No Java type for SQL type 1111 for column the_geom
2016-10-20 15:52:30,116 ERROR orm.ClassWriter (ClassWriter.java:myGenerateDbWrite(884)) - No Java type for SQL type 1111 for column the_geom
2016-10-20 15:52:30,116 ERROR orm.ClassWriter (ClassWriter.java:myGenerateHadoopRead(955)) - No Java type for SQL type 1111 for column the_geom
2016-10-20 15:52:30,116 ERROR orm.ClassWriter (ClassWriter.java:myGenerateHadoopWrite(1595)) - No Java type for SQL type 1111 for column the_geom
2016-10-20 15:52:30,117 ERROR orm.ClassWriter (ClassWriter.java:myGenerateHadoopWrite(1595)) - No Java type for SQL type 1111 for column the_geom
2016-10-20 15:52:30,117 ERROR orm.ClassWriter (ClassWriter.java:myGenerateToString(1314)) - No Java type for SQL type 1111 for column the_geom
2016-10-20 15:52:30,117 ERROR orm.ClassWriter (ClassWriter.java:myGenerateToString(1314)) - No Java type for SQL type 1111 for column the_geom
2016-10-20 15:52:30,117 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop (Sqoop.java:runSqoop(181)) - Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.parseNullVal(ClassWriter.java:1377)
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.parseColumn(ClassWriter.java:1402)
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.myGenerateParser(ClassWriter.java:1528)
```

Anybody have any idea how to import geometry data into hive,please suggest me.Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geometry datatype is not supported be default by Sqoop. You need to add it's mapping manually for Java(*for POJO class*).

Add this tag in your code:

```
--map-column-java the_geom=String
```

Final command:

```
sqoop import \
 --connect jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.130:5432/Analyst_Bangalore \
 --username postgres \
 --password track@123 \
 --map-column-java the_geom=String \
 --table state \
 -m 1 \
 --warehouse-dir /user/hive/warehouse/analytics.db
```

---

Add `--map-column-hive the_geom=string` if you using doing **hive import**.

Comment: Thank you so much dev.you solved my problem.Thanks a lot...............